# Reverse types in JOIN query with JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, left-join, criteria-api

I would like to return a list of `Group` objects using a JPA criteria query. A group can either **be empty or contain participants**. Each `Participant` has a reference to its `Group`. The group knows nothing about the participants. Now I would like to implement a criteria query to dynamically return either:

1. Only groups with participants.
2. All groups (including empty ones).

Basically, this is my `Group` class:

```
public class Group {
  private long id;
}
```

And this is my `Participant`:

```
public class Participant {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "FK_GROUP")
  private Group group;
}
```

*I left out all properties, methods and annotations for sake of simplicity.*

This will return both, empty groups and groups with participants, in plain SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT G.* FROM GROUP_TABLE G
  LEFT JOIN PARTICIPANT_TABLE P ON P.FK_GROUP=G.ID;
```

Now I'd like to do the same thing with Criteria API:

```
if (includeEmptyGroups) {
  // ...
  Root<Group> root = criteria.from(Group.class);
  Join<Participant, Group> join = root.join("id"); <-- This is my issue!
  criteria.select(root).distinct(true);
  //...
}
else {
  // ...
}
```

The query should return a list of `Group` objects, so I chose that type for my `Root` object and the `from()` method. Now, most tutorials would define a `Join<Group, Participant>`, and join participants by a property of the `Group` class.

Due to my *reversed* class structure, however, I cannot do this. The code above does not work, because I reversed the types and JPA cannot join by simple types. I'm unsure, if I approach the problem correctly at all.

I could switch types around and base my `Root` on the `Participant` class, then join with `Group`. This, however, makes it impossible to conditionally return empty groups. Is it even possible to build the plain SQL query with Criteria API?

Answer (score 0):

Since the JPA contracts do not allow for left joining entities, you can only use HQL or a query builder API on top of HQL like e.g. [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) which supports this. Either way, you will need at least Hibernate 5.1 which is the first version that added support for entity joins.